# Call a function with argument using buttons

Tags: javascript, button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, arguments

I want to execute a function using a button in a spreadsheet. But I also need to send arguments to the function like `function button1 (item, user) {program}`. I call the arguments: `item` and `user`.

When I create the button at the spreadsheet (Insert/Drawing/Form..) and I assign a script it gives me an error:

> "Script function button1 (2, 1) could not be found"

It works without arguments.

Is there any way to do call a function with arguments using buttons??

Edit for a better example:
I have 8 kind of items with different codes and 6 users working at the same time. We want to generate a DataBase for each kind of item, so...I create the function:
function request(user, item) {get the request and generate new code}.

So, as we work at the same time, I though to create 8 buttons per user that call the same function "request" and send "user" and "item" for ex:
request (1,'conveyor')

But it gives me the error I wrote before.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], meaning: add the source code that leads to the error!

Comment: Nope. Your function will need to infer its configuration by checking cells in the spreadsheet. Consider instead writing a sidebar and using an actual HTML button, for which you can build and send an event object based on whatever you desire.

Comment: Or you could write a function for each button that calls a generic function. function button1() { button(1); } function button2() { button(2); }

Comment: @GhostCat I though it was enough, but...I want to call the function: "function request(user,item) {
 sheet[0].getRange(15,4).setValue(item);
 sheet[0].getRange(13, 4).setValue(user);
 SpreadsheetApp.flush(); //actualiza celdas
}"

Comment: Don't put more information into comments, instead update your question.